# Setting the UIImagePickerController delegate throws a warning about UINavigationControllerDelegate

Tags: iphone

The code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

The warning, which shows up on the `picker.delegate = self;` line:

```
Class 'CardEditor' does not implement the 'UINavigationControllerDelegate' protocol
```

Why does the UIImagePickerController care if my class implements the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` inherits from `UINavigationController`. The delegate property is part of `UINavigationController`, so it requires that its delegate conforms to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol.

The [delegate property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/delegate) is declared like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UINavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

This tells the compiler to verify that your controller will implement the `UINavigationConrollerDelegate` protocol. The check is in place so that a compile-time warning can be generated if your controller class does not properly implement all of the methods that the `UINavigationController` might send to its delegate.

If you're looking for a solution, you can indicate (in your controller class interface) that your controller is compliant with that protocol:

```
@interface MyController : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
    ...
@end
```

Once this is done, the compiler will warn you about any required delegate methods that you haven't implemented. This is a good thing, as it will prevent you from releasing code that might accidentally throw a "method not found" runtime error.

Comment: Thanks for this, I just came across this error and you provided a quick solution :)

Comment: @e.James interface MyController : NSObject <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
    ...

Comment: Best anser I found for this problem.

Answer (score 16):

You can do it like this at the .h file

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 6):

e.James is right. Besides this `UINavigationControllerDelegate` only specifies optional methods. So a quick solution is to just let your view controller implement the protocol without implementing any of its methods.

I've checked all the Apple Sample code for implementations of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and they all don't implement any of the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods. So if you don't need them don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem then after a search found the solution i.e to add UINavigationControllerDelegate along with your UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in .h file.

```
@interface LatestJobsVC : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Hope that helps you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 4 :

@interface MyController : UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate